# Why is my flask app running with no modules installed in my environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, environment

I am using Anaconda to build environments. I've been using `pip install my_module` the entire time, and I've recently realized this is incorrect. The environment I made is called **dp_offfsets_environment** and I have been able to run my flask app I wrote in IntelliJ using an SDK linked to this environment.

Why is this? Seen below, when calling `conda list` no packages are installed under my environment so I would expect my flask app to fail.

What is `pip list` displaying below? Is it showing packages installed in my base environment?

How do you recommend uninstalling these packages and moving them into the actual environment?

```
(dp_offsets_environment) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -------
click                  8.0.3
colorama               0.4.4
cycler                 0.10.0
Flask                  2.0.2
fonttools              4.29.1
importlib-metadata     4.10.1
itsdangerous           2.0.1
Jinja2                 3.0.3
kiwisolver             1.3.1
MarkupSafe             2.0.1
matlab                 0.1
mysql-connector-python 8.0.26
packaging              21.3
pandas                 1.3.0
Pillow                 8.3.1
pip                    22.0.2
pyparsing              2.4.7
python-dateutil        2.8.1
pytz                   2021.1
setuptools             47.1.0
six                    1.16.0
typing_extensions      4.0.1
Werkzeug               2.0.2
wheel                  0.37.1
zipp                   3.7.0

(dp_offsets_environment) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ckurtz\.conda\envs\dp_offsets_environment:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

Comment: @merv since `conda list` is completely empty, I think the solution here is much simpler

Answer (score 1):

When you run `conda create -n dp_offsets_environment`, then `conda` creates an **empty** environment, i.e. with no packages. `conda` does not install `python`, `pip` or anything else in the environment. So when you run `pip` with that env activated, you will still get whatever `pip` is first located in your `PATH` (most likely from your `base` env).

So whenever you ran `pip install` nothing was installed to your currently active `conda` env and your flask app was probably not using that conda env, but also used the `python` that corresponds to your `pip`.

You need to install `python`/`pip` to your env and then install to your env.

See this as an example (I added annotation with `###`):

```
(base) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>where pip
C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe ### We are in base, so pip from base is found

(base) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>conda create -n someEnv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\envs\someEnv

### Note: No packages are being installed

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate someEnv
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate


(base) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>conda activate someEnv

(someEnv) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>where pip
C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe ### <----- pip still from base env

(someEnv) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>conda install python pip
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\envs\someEnv

  added / updated specs:
    - pip
    - python


### Download and installation pruned
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(someEnv) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>where pip
C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\envs\someEnv\Scripts\pip.exe ### Only now pip is in this env
C:\Users\FlyingTeller\miniconda3\Scripts\pip.exe

(someEnv) C:\Users\FlyingTeller>
```

---

**Side Note**

> I've been using pip install my_module the entire time, and I've recently realized this is incorrect

This is a misconception of a commonly given advice "Do not use `pip` in a `conda` env". This advice is always a bit strong. There is no reason to refrain from using `pip` in a `conda` env all together. There is a good reason to be careful and aware of certain things that can easily break your env. There is also a good post on [anaconda.org](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) about this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking back on this, I discovered I had another instance of Anaconda on my machine. My company gives out laptops with Spyder installed which by default, has it's own version of Anaconda. I did not know Spyder came with Anaconda so I accidently installed two versions of Anaconda during my initial setup. To fix this I had to go through and uninstall both instances of Anaconda on my machine including their packages. Once completely removed, I reinstalled Anaconda, and my problems were alleviated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).